# Dispatcher not showing results from an AJAX call to an OSGi bundle

Tags: aem

In my project, we have a component that includes a JavaScript file & in that file, we are making an AJAX call to a Servlet (defined in an OSGi bundle).

When the package is installed in the Publish instance (along with the OSGi bundle), I'm able to see results after I click on a link which is bound to the AJAX call.

When accessing the same page through the Dispatcher however, the page is getting displayed but the link which should show content from the OSGi bundle is not working. The same link is working fine when accessed directly via the Publish instance

---

*Updated:*

The access.log in Dispatcher (Apache Web Server)

**Success log of dispatcher**

```
domain - - [11/Jul/2014:15:25:11 +0530] "GET /content/sample.html HTTP/1.1" 200 25805
```

**Failure log on one of the links on the above page**

```
domain - - [11/Jul/2014:15:25:12 +0530] "GET /bin/servlet/SampleServlet?action=GET_SAMPLE_USAGE HTTP/1.1" 404 230
```

It is not finding `GET_SAMPLE_USAGE` servlet, but the same is already available in the OSGi bundle and is working perfectly fine via the Publish instance (logs below).

**Publisher access.log**

```
domain - admin 11/Jul/2014:15:24:31 +0530 "GET /content/sample.html HTTP/1.1" 200 25805 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"

domain - admin 11/Jul/2014:15:24:31 +0530 "GET /bin/servlet/SampleServlet?action=GET_SAMPLE_USAGE HTTP/1.1" 200 -     [this is not a link] ( "domain:4503/content/sample.html" ) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"
```

Comment: No links, no codes, no errors, no help.

Comment: @Raptor Please find the updated logs in the description..

Comment: Is /bin path allowed in your webserver or is it blocked?

Comment: @rakhi4110 Thanks, its working now, access was denied earlier... :-)